# Java library + app to send push messages to android device

Tags: java, android, notifications, push, message

I am doing a lot of long lasting computation stuff in java and want to stay informed.

Is there any standard method ( library etc. ) to send push notifications from a desktop java program to my Android device?

When there is no , could someone provide me with some starting ideas how to write this on my own?

Answer (score 0):

The "3rd-party application server" mentioned in https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html can also be a desktop pc running a simple java program.

You will need to setup some IDs, an app that receives push messages, a way to display the phone registration ID so you can enter it in the desktop app.

But the rest is basically as simple as adding the gcm server jar to a desktop app (I'd use this version here: https://github.com/kurthuwig/gcm/commit/d37f4d1c37ed8deaf1a161ca7b881c1d843f80df ) and then calling 3 methods or so.

Answer (score 0):

Like what zapl suggested I would say GCM is a good choice. Also, all benefits aside, if you're into messaging you can have a go at [AMQP](http://www.amqp.org/), specially the [RabbitMQ implementation](http://simonwdixon.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/getting-started-with-rabbitmq-on-android-part-1/). You can run the RabbitMQ server on your desktop and push your messages out to all listening devices.